# Will deleting Apache access log break Subversion?

Tags: svn, apache

We have subversion installed and running with apache server.

The apache access log is now half a gig, will deleting it or moving it break SVN?
I would assume the access log is purely loggin access to the server but I just want to make sure before I delete or move it.

I understand you cannot set a size limit on the access log so whats the best way to backup it up on a regular basis?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can safely move or remove Apache's access log without affecting Subversion.

Take a look at the [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html) program that comes with Apache. It supports rotation of its log files based on time or the size of the file.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not break subversion.

The best way is to probably zip it and back it up.  Only go back as far as you need though - do you need to refer back to old access logs?